# OpenXml docx how to add CRLF into inserted text?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

In an OpenXml document there are content controls that get filled with data, but the CRLF's do not bind or go with the Word document.  sentences run together instead of having a new line.

In the code to write the value into the content control, there is a newline, "\n" added, so 
        `case "custname":
        cc.Descendants<Text>().First().Text =`customer1 + "\n" + customer2 + "\n"

which has no effect, no CRLF

In the HTML textareaFor however it sees the formatting and applies it just fine, but when its put into the word docx, the sentences have no CRLF.  have tried adding in 0x0a, 0x0d.  In the documentation it looks like what should get added is:

```
    <w:br w:type="textWrapping" w:clear="all" />
```

just after the part that should have the CRLF, so perhaps the other question is how to add such a tag + payload into the openxml right there?

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.break%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

In OpenXml the construction of a paragraph is special.
The tag Text should only contain text, CRLR is a formatting and not a text.

To do what you want, you have to :

- Retrieve the run you want to modify
- Add a couple of

The example is

```
case "custname":
Run run = cc.Descendants<Run>().First();
foreach(string customer in customers)
{
run.Append(new Text(customer));
run.Append(new Break());
}
```

You should have to adapt this code to :

- Retrieve the run you want
- loop on your customers / don't add the last break

Comment: Yes, this does work to add the effect of CRLF in the word doc, thanks;  What i have found since is that the text needs to be bulleted.  Since its a content control, it 'should' work if using a Richtext CC where multiple lines with the bullet char can be added.  For some reason the problem seems to be in the CC always turning into plaintext CC, silently.  I am trying to figure out how to add the list paragraph with bullet item

Comment: The simplest way to find an example of what you want to create is to do it on word, save it, rename the file with a .zip extension, open the file word/document.xml (who is in the zip) and reproduce what word does for you

Comment: Yes thats true, i am using the open xml sdk 2.5 productivity tool http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425   what happens is i can replace a paragraph, or append, but Word will not open it, says its corrupt.  the xml seems to look ok.  also, this lets visual studio edit the xml, https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b   easy to edit and save.  doesnt work on VS2015 yet?

Comment: when word says its corrupt I edit the document.xml to add crlf. When you reopen the file, word precise the exact line of corruption.
If you have Tables a common mistake is "the last element of a cell is not a paragraph" (word got me several times with that one)

Comment: I hope its this simple, I started a new thread or question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703771/how-to-add-openxml-list-paragraph-with-bullets-to-content-control   because there is code and word doc and xml.  it should be simple to fix but am not seeing the answer