# How to add OpenXml list paragraph with bullets to content control?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml

Im using a Word 2013 .docx as a template thats opened in the openxml code, the content controls are filled in then its saved, downloaded to the user and that part works fine.

In one content control the goal is to add a bulleted list.   The problem comes from trying to append or replace the new paragraph, which is generated from a method.  This method works fine, i send it the variable and it returns a paragraph with a bullet.   It inserts, but it corrupts the word doc;

Shown below are the template.docx (upper) and resulting.docx (lower) only the paragraph in the lower one is different, after multiline=1 where the blank area is; the rest is identical.  if I remove run elements, save, try, I could get the word doc to open and see the formatted bullet list there so that part "works",  but what is the error?

```
  public static Paragraph GenerateParagraph(string bulletText)
    {
        var element =
        new Paragraph(
        new ParagraphProperties(
        new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "ListParagraph" },
        new NumberingProperties(
        new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 1 },
        new NumberingId() { Val = 2 })),
        new Run(
        new Text(bulletText)) //Text you want to insert with bullet
        ) { RsidParagraphAddition = "00031711", RsidParagraphProperties = "00031711", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00031711" };
        return element;
    }`
```

the word doc:

```
     <w:sdt>
<w:sdtPr>
 <w:rPr>
  <w:b w:val="0"/>
  <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
  <w:sz w:val="24"/>
  <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
 </w:rPr>
 <w:tag w:val="custMilestones"/>
 <w:id w:val="-1610118874"/>
 <w:placeholder>
  <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_1081868574"/>
 </w:placeholder>
 <w:multiLine w:val="1"/>

   * in the file compare this original file was different, in this area with missing lines















</w:sdtPr>
<w:sdtEndPr/>
<w:sdtContent>
 <w:r w:rsidRPr="002C1BAC">
  <w:rPr>
   <w:b w:val="0"/>
   <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
   <w:sz w:val="24"/>
   <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">

  </w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidR="00DD453F">
  <w:rPr>
   <w:b w:val="0"/>
   <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
   <w:sz w:val="24"/>
   <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">

  </w:t>
 </w:r>
</w:sdtContent>
```

and the generated file:

```
       <w:sdt>
<w:sdtPr>
 <w:rPr>
  <w:b w:val="0"/>
  <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
  <w:sz w:val="24"/>
  <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
 </w:rPr>
 <w:tag w:val="custMilestones"/>
 <w:id w:val="-1610118874"/>
 <w:placeholder>
  <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_1081868574"/>
 </w:placeholder>
 <w:multiLine w:val="1"/>
 <w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00031711" w:rsidP="00031711" w:rsidRDefault="00031711">
   <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
     <w:ilvl w:val="1"/>
     <w:numId w:val="2"/>
    </w:numPr>
   </w:pPr>
   <w:r>
    <w:t>
      Summary of outlines including the details of customer products and part numbers.
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:p>
 </w:p>
</w:sdtPr>
<w:sdtEndPr/>
<w:sdtContent>
 <w:r w:rsidRPr="002C1BAC">
  <w:rPr>
   <w:b w:val="0"/>
   <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
   <w:sz w:val="24"/>
   <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">

  </w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidR="00DD453F">
  <w:rPr>
   <w:b w:val="0"/>
   <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
   <w:sz w:val="24"/>
   <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">

  </w:t>
 </w:r>
</w:sdtContent>
```

And the code that runs, the word doc has a richtext content control*  (it was setup with the richtext cc) called custMilestones as the tagname and there is one space in the contentcontrol otherwise the code throws an object reference not set exception.

```
      byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainDoc = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                Body bodyDoc = mainDoc.Document.Body;

                  foreach (var cc in wordDoc.ContentControls())
                {
                    SdtProperties props = cc.Elements<SdtProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
                    Tag tag = props.Elements<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
                    dat1 = tag.Val.ToString();
                    switch (dat1)
                    {
                      case "custMilestones":

                         props.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
                         props.AppendChild<Paragraph>(new Paragraph(GenerateParagraph(custmilestone1)));

                       break;
                    default:
                       break;
                   }
```

edit 7/30/15 with resulting xml making oddly styled results:

```
     <w:sdt>
   <w:sdtPr>
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rStyle w:val="Style1"/>
     <w:b w:val="0"/>
     <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:tag w:val="custmiles"/>
    <w:id w:val="568603642"/>
    <w:placeholder>
     <w:docPart w:val="D9E50C82EA8C4C45A237822288EB36B5"/>
    </w:placeholder>
    <w:showingPlcHdr/>
    <w15:appearance w15:val="hidden"/>
   </w:sdtPr>
   <w:sdtEndPr>
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rStyle w:val="DefaultParagraphFont"/>
     <w:sz w:val="36"/>
    </w:rPr>
   </w:sdtEndPr>
   <w:sdtContent>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00B87AB0" w:rsidR="00E73294">
     <w:rPr>
      <w:b w:val="0"/>
      <w:sz w:val="24"/>
      <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
     </w:rPr>
     <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
    </w:r>
   </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00B87AB0" w:rsidR="00C06C61">
   <w:rPr>
    <w:b w:val="0"/>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
   </w:rPr>
   <w:tab/>
   <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
     <w:id w:val="-206335861"/>
     <w:placeholder>
      <w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_1081868574"/>
     </w:placeholder>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00816E2A" w:rsidR="00816E2A" w:rsidP="00816E2A">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
       <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="1"/>
       </w:numPr>
       <w:ind w:leftChars="0"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:t>
        this is test sentence1 for the software to make lists with numbers
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00816E2A" w:rsidR="00816E2A" w:rsidP="00816E2A">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
       <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="1"/>
       </w:numPr>
       <w:ind w:leftChars="0"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:t>
        this is test sentence2 for the software to make lists with numbers
       </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
     </w:p>
     <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00816E2A" w:rsidR="00546790" w:rsidP="00816E2A">
      <w:pPr>
       <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
       <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="1"/>
       </w:numPr>
       <w:ind w:leftChars="0"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
       <w:t>
        this is test sentence3 for the software to make lists with numbers         </w:t>
      </w:r>
     </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
   </w:sdt>
  </w:r>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you insert your Paragraph inside the `<w:sdtPr>` Tag instead of the `<w:sdtContent>` tag.

```
<w:sdtPr>
...
 <w:p>
  <w:p w:rsidR="00031711" w:rsidP="00031711" w:rsidRDefault="00031711">
...
  </w:p>
 </w:p>
</w:sdtPr>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtblock(v=office.14).aspx indicate where to put the Paragraph

And more, you have a Paragraph inside a Paragraph, I don't think Word like that

edit : tags sdtPr and sdtContent didn't appears

Comment: Im struggling trying to insert this within the sdtContent

Comment: If you are on your w:Std component, find the StdContent with `comp.Elements<StdContent>().GetFirstOrDefault()` and if you are on w:StdPr find it with `comp.NextSiblin<StdContent>().GetFirstOrDefault()`.
and if the result is not null, just do a .Append(p) on it

Comment: i could not figure out how to get the cc.Elements<SdtContent> it gets SdtContentCell or Block, and it will not allow the .GetFirstOrDefault()

Comment: if you take a look in the link i set in the answer, in the section "Remarks" you can find the information `SdtContentBlock <w:sdtContent>`
Try `cc.Elements<SdtContentBlock>().ElementAtOrDefault(0)`

Comment: ok, using cc.ChildElements.GetItem(1).Append(p);  happens to insert the paragraph in the right place, but Word has 2 problems: first the font and size are Bold, 18.  must be regular, 12.  Second, the text thats there in the Word doc is locked from the user.  you can select and copy it but thats all, it cannot be edited.  why is this??  The goal was to put text into the doc and have the user be able to edit, its a requirement.  I found that bullet chars make the text wrap around wrong; numbers keep the text aligned but no matter how i set the template.docx its bold/18

Comment: Could you paste the xml you obtain ? without the result it's hard to tell what the problem is

Comment: Yes, I have edited the original because of the long xml, so the productivity tool was used to compare and copy the different/new xml and its in the first post up there, thanks

Comment: this worked, now its crashing "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" in different code
            `RunProperties runProp = new RunProperties(); 
            RunFonts runFont = new RunFonts();    
            runFont.Ascii = "Times New Roman";      
            Bold bold = new Bold() { Val = false };
            
            FontSize size = new FontSize();
            size.Val = new StringValue("24"); 
            runProp.Append(runFont);
            runProp.Append(size);
            runProp.Append(bold);

            run1.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp);`

Comment: case "custmiles":
      cc.NextSibling().AppendChild(GenerateSdtBlock());  <--exception
      break;

Comment: The simplest way to find your problem is step by step. 
I think your problem come from `run1.PrependChild<RunProperties>(runProp)` it must not find a <RunProperties> element so PrependChild can't work. Identify the line the error occured and look for a null value (you can see if PrependChild could work by doing a run1.FirstOrDefault<RunProperties>() and check if the null or not)

Comment: The problem turned out to be in the Word docx file template;  i had pulled in a previously used template.docx used before and it ran.  I did this step by step going back to where it was.  So there was a workaround; foreach openxmlelement xde in bodyDoc, if xde.InnerText == "Custmiles"  xde.InsertAfterSelf new break(), xde.InsertAfterSelf(generateSDTblock())  where the generateSDTblock is about 200 lines of code to make a custom SDT with styles, properties, fonts, run(s).  just got away from trying to use the content control, they aren't working right for me